# Different values for same static members in same domain

Tags: c#, static

I'm hosting a C# program with a VC++ project. This C# program is using `Remoting` namespace and following method initialize Remoting:

```
public static void Create(...)
{
    var type = typeof(ClassA);

    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(type, ServiceNAME, WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
}
```

`ClassA` use static members of another class, When data sent on a specified port Remoting makes an instance of `ClassA`; when this happened static members in another class (ClassB) is reinitialized. In other word we have two different value for static members in same time, same Domain and same Process (I've checked it).

**NOTE:** ClassB is a class of my project that contains some static members and when I use following command :

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("ClassB").TypeHandle.Value
```

it returns different value inside of ClassA and outside it.

**NOTE:** This program works right without using hosting. My hosting project works right with many other projects and there is no something special.

Why there is two value for a static member? Why the value of TypeHandle is different for same type?

Comment: Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I try to add some details. I'll add more details If something is not clear.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Maarten: I added my question explicitly. Thanks

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is there anything that can be useful to add my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this happened but following solution resolved my problem:

In this project I'm handling AssemblyResolve event. When Remoting want to make an instance of ClassA, AssemblyResolve is triggered with assembly name itself; In this case you should store assembly object of specified assemlby. When AssemblyResolve method is triggered with assembly name return stored assembly object.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank for your attention. This resolved my problem unbelievably. :)